# Infinite loop of jQuery focus() event with a <select> element

Tags: javascript, focus, jquery, onfocus

I have this HTML:

```
<select id="select-one">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">House</option>
</select>

<select id="select-two">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="A">Table</option>
</select>
```

And this Javascript with JQuery

```
$("#select-two").focus( function() {

    if( $("#select-one").val() == "" ) {
        alert("Fill select-one first!");
        return false;
    }

});
```

So i am getting a infinite loop with alerts because after call `alert()` Javascript puts the focus again in the same select (select-two).

Someone can help me to solve this please?

Comment: Listen to `change` event instead of `focus`.

Comment: @undefined, I need to use .focus() of some logical rules in my code

Comment: @Boaz, I have to use .focus() in my specific code

Comment: Rather than using an alert, perhaps some error text above or next to the select box so you aren't changing focus?

Comment: @WingLian, Nice tip! If i don't get a better solution, i will do this. Please put your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: based on your comments, this assumes you must listen to the focus event.

---

**Solution 1 - using `blur()` - effective but buggy in Chrome**

In theory, the `focus` event is not cancelable, so `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` will have no effect in this case. However, in practice, you can reverse the event by using the `blur()` method.

For example:

```
$('#select-two').on('focus',function () {
    if ($("#select-one").val() == "") {
        $(this).blur();
        alert('Fill select-one first!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EuUjr/2/)**

This effectively prevents the field from regaining focus after the `alert` call and so the `focus` event is not repeated. The only problem is that in Chrome even though the field is not focused anymore, the dropdown remains open (see demo).

---

**Solution 2 - using `remove()` and `clone()` - costly but cross-browser**

If Chrome's behavior is problematic, you can take a more crude approach, whereby you `remove()` the `select` from the DOM, `clone()` it and then reinsert it into the DOM. This will effectively "reset" the `select` element completely, leaving it without focus as well as closed.

For example:

```
$(document).on('focus','#select-two',function (e) {
    if ($("#select-one").val() == "") {
        $(this).remove().clone().insertAfter('#select-one');
        alert('Fill select-one first!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29Mvy/1/)**

The upside of this approach is that it works well in Chrome too. The downside of this approach is that it involves manipulating the DOM for a very trivial issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an extra event that change content select-two when the value of select-one has "" like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select-one">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">House</option>
</select>

<select id="select-two">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="A">Table</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#select-one").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $("#select-two").val("");
    }
});

$("#select-two").focus(function() {
    if( $("#select-one option:selected").val() == "" ) {
        alert("Fill select-one first!");
        $("#select-one").focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Soldier/TkZAp/5/)