# How do I do something when a text input is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input, focus

Complete beginner at jQuery here, I'm assuming the answer to this is easy, so I apologise.

I have a login form like this:

```
<table id="login_form">
    <tr>
        <td class="login_label">Username: </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="login_input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="login_label">Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" class="login_input" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the jQuery code of:

```
$(".login_input")
    .focus(function(){
        alert("Why do I never get this alert?");
    }
);
```

why, when I click on either of the two text input fields, does the alert not display? If I change "focus" to "ready" then I get the alert so I'm assuming it's something to with that.

Comment: give both input boxes a separate ID and then add focus listner to them

Comment: I am afraid that with those fixes you will get alerts one after another.

Comment: but you can show different messages for both

Comment: @shadow: I was not referring to you comment but to solution to just wrap code with $(document).ready() without other changes. I tried it but when alert shows I have to press OK, after that field get focus back and alert is shown again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so that the binding code is executed when elements are added to DOM and DOM is ready. The ready works in your code as it waits to get elements added in DOM.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/PqX6j/)**

```
$(document).read(function(){
   $(".login_input").focus(function(){
        alert("Why do I never get this alert?");
    });
});
```

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely
>   on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference
>   external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the
>   scripts, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/vNCs2/

API:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.

**Code**

```
$(function () {
$(".login_input").focus(function(){
        alert("now you do?");
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `$(document).read(function(){<code here>});` which will run the code after document is ready:

```
$(document).read(function(){
   $(".login_input").focus(function(){
        alert("Why do I never get this alert?");
   });
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/2DS3g/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why alert does not show up is missing wrapper `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Adding that produce another problem, inifinite loop of alerts:

- you select one of the fields
- the field gets focus
- focus event if fired
- alert is shown
- you click OK or ESC
- alert is closed
- field gets focus back
- focus event is fired again...

Why is this so is described in [Infinite loop of jQuery focus() event with a  element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035041/infinite-loop-of-jquery-focus-event-with-a-select-element). You can try using `$(this).blur();`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".login_input").focus(function() {
        $(this).blur();
        alert("Here is my alert!");
    });
});
```

but the problem will be almost the same.

In some real application most probably you will not call alert(). For example, changing `alert()` to `console.log` fix the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".login_input").focus(function() {
        console.log("field in focus");
    });
});
```